# Is there an interface that functions as an Iterator using generator?

Tags: php, class, iterator, generator

I want to create a directory class, and I want it to function as an iterator (foreach-able).
But I want it to be generator based (for example a function that does "yield").
Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is not an interface explicitly for classes to implement generators, but you can make use of `IteratorAggregate` here.

See this example of implementing `IteratorAggregate` from the [Generators RFC](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/generators)

```
class Test implements IteratorAggregate {
    protected $data;

    public function __construct(array $data) {
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    public function getIterator() {
        foreach ($this->data as $key => $value) {
            yield $key => $value;
        }
        // or whatever other traversation logic the class has
    }
}

$test = new Test(['foo' => 'bar', 'bar' => 'foo']);
foreach ($test as $k => $v) {
    echo $k, ' => ', $v, "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Generators **are** Iterators.

From http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.generators.object.php

> When a generator function is called for the first time, an object of the internal Generator class is returned. This object implements the Iterator interface in much the same way as a forward-only iterator object would.

Comment: But they will be introduced in 5.5

Comment: Yes. The question referred to"yield", so I assumed it was about PHP 5.5

Comment: Generators are absolutely NOT iterators. While they do implement much of the Iterator interface, the rewind method in particular behaves completely differently (throwing exceptions once you have started to iterate). It throws an exception once you have started to iterate rather than resets you back to the start. For most use cases where you only iterate forward, and only once they appear to behave exactly the same. For other uses cases they break though.

Comment: I agree to your statement "Generators are Iterators". (are/is stands for inherits - the L in solid)

The inheritance chain is as follows (PHP8.2):

Generator --> Iterator --> Traversable --> iterable.

Keep in mind that arrays are also interable

array|Traversable --> iterable